# How to set index of element inside list with lists in python?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a list variable with sets inside. As a set is unordered and its elements do not have indexes I am changing it to list and then I want to loop through it and don't change the position of elements but every time when I loop it gives me a randomly assigned index and value.

```
test = [{"2015", "teacher", "cz", "m", "Paris"}, {"2011", "teacher", "en", "w", "London"},{"2018", "teacher", "ua", "m", "Berlin"}]
    
def get_data(test):
 for sets in test:
  lists = list(sets)
   for item in enumerate(lists):
     print(item)
get_data(test)
```

Comment: Sets don't have order, which means you can't get an order out of them. Converting to a list will make a list that maintains order, but the initial order is unspecified.

Comment: @Aplet123 and how to specify the initial order when changing sets to lists?

Comment: You don't. That's what not having an order means.

Comment: If you want it to be in a specific order, then why can't you just make a nested list? e.g. `[["2015", "teacher", "cz", "m", "Paris"], etc.]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the order and indexes to be stable from one run to the next, use sorted() to convert your sets to lists:

i.e. change `lists = list(sets)` to `lists = sorted(sets)`

Answer (score 0):

The items you have are simply not suitable for having stored as sets. Sets are just a pile of things, maintaining no order inside, meant to contain similar stuff where order does not matter, only being or not being part of the set. While you seem to have something like year-occupation-nationality-gender-location things, which could be organized by labels (using dictionaries, `{"year":2015,"occupation":"teacher"...}` and the like) or by the order you are asking about, which would be lists or tuples.

You might be confusing `{sets}` with `(tuples)`. They are not lists (you clearly know about lists already), and they maintain order:

```
test = [("2015", "teacher", "cz", "m", "Paris"),("2011", "teacher", "en", "w", "London"),("2018", "teacher", "ua", "m", "Berlin")]
    
def get_data(test):
  for sets in test:
    lists = list(sets)
    for item in enumerate(lists):
      print(item)
get_data(test)
```

will always produce the same output.